# What are Translation and Rotation coordinates relative to in camera calibration?

Tags: c++, opencv, camera-calibration

When I use the calibrateCamera() fucntion in OpenCV I get the translation and rotation vectors for each image used. Are these coordinates relative to the camera or the chessboard?

Comment: It is the position of the camera with respect to the reference point on the chessboard.

Comment: Thank you for a quick answer!

Comment: You can check [here](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dc/dbb/tutorial_py_calibration.html)